# firebase auth and Firestone error code in swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, error-handling

I have followed some tutorial but no one seams to work I need to get AuthErrorCode for firebase auth and Firestone for make the localizable this is my code

this is the login function where I need to call the errorHandlingFunction

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailTextField, password: passwordTextField) {result, error in
                if error != nil {
                    self.alertMessage = self.errorHandling(error: error! as NSError)
                    self.showAlert.toggle()
                    self.isLoading = false
                    return
                }
```

```
func errorHandling(error: NSError) -> String {
    
        if let err = error as NSError?, let code = AuthErrorCode(rawValue: error.code)
        {
    
            switch code {
            case .accountExistsWithDifferentCredential:
                return String(localized: "Account already exist with different credetial", table: "Localization", comment: "alert message")
            case .credentialAlreadyInUse:
                return String(localized: "Credential are already in use", table: "Localization", comment: "alert message")
            case .unverifiedEmail:
                return String(localized: "An email link was sent to your account, please verify it before loggin in", table: "Localization", comment: "alert message")
            case .userDisabled:
                return String(localized: "User is currently disabled", table: "Localization", comment: "alert message")
            case .userNotFound:
                return String(localized: "Canno't find the user, try with different credential", table: "Localization", comment: "alert message")
            case .weakPassword:
                return String(localized: "Password is too weak", table: "Localization", comment: "alert message")
            case .networkError:
                return String(localized: "Error in network connection", table: "Localization", comment: "alert message")
            case .wrongPassword:
                return String(localized: "Password is wrong", table: "Localization", comment: "alert message")
            case .invalidEmail:
                return String(localized: "Email is not valid", table: "Localization", comment: "alert message")
            default:
                return String(localized: "Unknown error occurred", table: "Localization", comment: "alert message")
            }
        }
    }
```

but I get this error from compiler

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'AuthErrorCode.Code'
```

is there a solution? and also for Firestone?

thanks

Comment: The error is pretty clear; you're attempting to pass an `Int` to a function that is expecting an `AuthErrorCode.Code` and my guess is that you want to pass something along the the lines of `AuthErrorCode.Code.rawValue`. There's annother issue in that a nil value will cause the entire block of code to fail so let me add an answer that may help simplify the code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is likely due to a function wanting a `Code` instead of an `Int`, according to the error. Let's simplify to handle all cases:

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: user, password: pw, completion: { (auth, error) in
    if let maybeError = error { //if there was an error, handle it
        let err = maybeError as NSError
        switch err.code {
        case AuthErrorCode.wrongPassword.rawValue:
            print("wrong password")
        case AuthErrorCode.invalidEmail.rawValue:
            print("invalid email")
        case AuthErrorCode.accountExistsWithDifferentCredential.rawValue:
            print("accountExistsWithDifferentCredential")
        ... add the rest of the case statements
        default:
            print("unknown error: \(err.localizedDescription)")
        }
    } else { //there was no error so the user could be auth'd or maybe not!
        if let _ = auth?.user {
            print("user is authd")
        } else {
            print("no authd user")
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Do you also have an example fore manage error in the same way from Firestone database? thanks

Comment: @NicolaRigoni The auth code is the same. [Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/start) is a separate Firebase product than Storage, The RealtimeDatabase and Firestore and can be stand-alone for use with other third party products as well.

Comment: yes, I mean for Firestore how can I get the same ?

Comment: @NicolaRigoni Authentication doesn't use Firestore or the Realtime Database. It's a separate product and doesn't rely on either one. The code in my answer works in both environments.

Answer (score 4):

To initialize a code you should go with

```
let nsError = error as NSError
AuthErrorCode.Code.init(rawValue: nsError.code)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailTextField, password: passwordTextField) {result, error in

    if let error = error {

        let err = error as NSError
        if let authErrorCode = AuthErrorCode.Code(rawValue: err.code) {

            switch authErrorCode {

            case .wrongPassword:
                print("wrong password")
            case .invalidEmail:
                print("invalid email")
            // ... other cases
            default:
                print("unknown error")
            }            
        }

        return
    }
}
```